# Query the database using a T-SQLvariable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Am new to T-SQL. I have a variable holding table name. How I query the same table using this variable as

```
DECLARE @tb_name varchar(300)
SET @tb_name = 'tbl_deleted_shipmentdata_record'
select * from  @tb_name
```

Comment: just search for dynamic sql, it's been asked many times, see the below duplicate

Comment: I don't know th term for searching.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Robert_Junior, before you go down the dynamic SQL path, peruse SQL Server MVP Erland Sommarskog's thorough article on the topic.  It's not just a question of how you to do this, but should you.  http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @tb_name VARCHAR(300)
SET @tb_name = 'tbl_deleted_shipmentdata_record'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(300)  = 'select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@tb_name)
EXEC( @sql)
```

`QUOTENAME` function surrounds `@tb_name` variable with `[tbl_deleted_shipmentdata_record]`. Just to minimize risk of `sql injection`.

Answer (score 4):

YOu need to write dynamic SQL for that.

```
DECLARE @tb_name varchar(300)
SET @tb_name = 'tbl_deleted_shipmentdata_record'

Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max)
 SET @SQL = 'select * from '+ @tb_name
Exec SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```